# select all data with the same foriegn key

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

Hi guys i am having a problem selecting all data in data base with the same foreign key. but this code is running in simple php and html table but if i call the variable in FPDF it only shows 1 row with foreign key. I want to display all data depends on foreign key assigned

```
$queryDrinfo = "select * from drinfo";
$resultDrinfo = $mysqli->query($queryDrinfo)
while($rowDrinfo = $resultDrinfo->fetch_assoc()){
    $id = $rowDrinfo['id'];
    $drnum = $rowDrinfo['drnum'];

    $queryItems = "select * from items where drinfo_id=".$rowDrinfo['id'];
    $resultItems = $mysqli->query($queryItems);
    while($rowItems = $resultItems->fetch_assoc()){

        $itemnum = $rowItems['itemnum'];
        $description = $rowItems['description'];
        $qty = $rowItems['qty']; 
        $unit = $rowItems['unit'];
        $remarks = $rowItems['remarks'];

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->SetY(57.5);
        $pdf->SetX(50);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$id,0);

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->SetY(57.5);
        $pdf->SetX(50);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$drnum,0);

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->SetY(1);
        $pdf->SetX(50);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$drinfo_id,0); 

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->SetY(51);
        $pdf->SetX(50);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$itemnum,0); 

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->SetY(55);
        $pdf->SetX(50);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$description,0);

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->SetY(58);
        $pdf->SetX(50);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$qty,0); 

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->SetY(62);
        $pdf->SetX(50);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$unit,0);

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->SetY(66);
        $pdf->SetX(50);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$remarks,0);
```

Comment: It looks to me like you are painting all the data in the same place in the PDF. So I guess you are reading all the data, just overwriting it all with the next result row

Comment: And the same thing is probably happening with your other ___very similiar question___ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293681/fpdf-cannot-display-all-data-in-the-database-with-the-same-foriegn-key

Comment: how sir please help me.

Comment: Its been a while since I used fpdf. But I read the manual and worked it out

Comment: help me in my problem please.

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=es